# Quickest way to select last edge loop?

Tags: modeling

Got a cube and can select the internal edge loops easy enough with alt+right click. How ever the last loop which makes an external face won't select in the same way? What's the quickest way to select this loop in an editing workflow?

[See the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgmQijOkNb8)

Comment: Please add a picture to illustrate your question better.

Comment: Thanks Ray, couldn't figure out to do a gif, so added an YouTube video.

Comment: It happens because there are two or more possible loops. I can not help you with a solution other than loop selection each of the four outer edges of that side of the cube, but I'm hoping someone else can, since this occasionally annoys me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases of hard surface meshes like blocks, buildings etc. it's possible to select faces similar by normals or co-planar faces and convert that into the boundary loop.

1. Select one face in the area around which you'd like to select 4 edge loops.
2. Select similar faces of that area (use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > *Normal* or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > *Co-planar*).
3. From the *Select* menu in the 3D Viewport header find *Select Boundary Loop* (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and find it in the list).

[image: GIF selecting corner boundary loop]

Note that this most likely will select more than expected once your geometry is complex enough (e.g. there are more blocks like this where faces' normals are pointed into the same direction etc.)

---

One more possible thing is to select edges by their sharpness. It's accessible through *Select* > *Sharp Edges*. Similar effect will have <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > *Face Angles*.

[image: screenshot of selecting sharp edges]

Note that this will select sharp edges across *all* the mesh (above some threshold).

Comment: Thanks that's really useful, in an ideal world not as fast as I'd like, but still great, also like that shift + g menu.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to select a face loop is to switch to Edge Select Mode and select the four edges manually. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+RMB while selecting.

[image: select edges in edge select mode]

You are way better off to perform "pure" edge loop selections in Edge Select Mode anyway, because selecting edges won't automatically select vertices and thus whole faces.

[image: select loopcuts in edge select mode]